# Запятая? Не могу разобраться с ее постановкой

Tags: пунктуация

*Предложение:* "Благодаря переводам Боэция, выдержки из его трудов были известны уже в VI веке нашей эры, а в полном объеме он стал изучаться с XIII века".

*Вопрос:* разве здесь надо ставить запятую после слова "Боэция"? Нельзя сказать, что здесь деепричастный оборот, тогда что?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы правы, *благодаря* в данном случае ***предлог.*** Обособление оборота с ним факультативно, смотрите [здесь](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_56) и [здесь](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum-attach1) (по второй ссылке можно пройти из первой).

На мой взгляд, следующий пример с обособлением похож на ваш:

> *Благодаря этим наводящим вопросам, Дунька рассказала по порядку всё происшествие.* Д. Мамин-Сибиряк, Озорник.

Однако я считаю, что *не ставить запятую* вы тоже имеете *полное право.* Приведу такой аргумент:

> Обычно обособляются обороты, которые:
> <...>
>
> - находятся **не в начале и не в конце предложения**

Из этого напрашивается вывод, что оборот в начале предложения, как у нас, *совсем не обязательно* обособляется.